# WSDL for service accepting different messages in a single operation

Tags: web-services, xsd, wsdl

I'd like to have a document\literal web-service accepting different kind of input in `soap:body`. Smth like

```xml
<soap:body>
   <A xmlns="http://tempuri/A">
   </A>
</soap:body>
```

as well as

```xml
<soap:body>
   <B xmlns="http://tempuri/B">
   </B>
</soap:body>
```

in the same `wsdl:operation`.

I tried describing  and  elements in inline schema block inside WSDL, but for a document\literal-style i need to specify an element for a `wsdl:message` part. But I don't want to wrap the request (`<A>` or `<B>`) into another container element.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible. The only way can get it working is to wrap those `A` and `B` elements with the other element for e.g. `C`. Then you need to specify that `C` element in your `WSDL` message.

Why this not possible because you have two different elements pointing at two different namespaces and the message only allows one element from one namespace.

Comment: does this means it would be possible if A and B belong to same namespace?

Comment: No, you still need to wrap them into the one C element, C element then can contain as many different elements as you want. You can create two different operations with A and B elements, but as I understand this is not an option for you.